# JPQL query for left outer join over parent vs inherited object

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

```
Entities/Model:

@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserAccount implements CommonUserAccount {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    @Embedded
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo(); // name/surname - regular stuff

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "UserAccountTags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", nullable = false))
    @Column(name = "tag")
    //@Transient
    private Set<String> tags = new HashSet<String>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "UserAccountRoles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", nullable = false))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "userRole")
    private Set<UserAccountRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserAccountRole>();

    // regular getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "useraccountid")
public class DemoUserAccount extends UserAccount implements CommonUserAccount {

    @Column
    private String passwordHash;

    @Column
    private Long failedLogins;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    Date lockedAt;

    // regular getters/setters
}
```

Question:
Is it possible to build query using JPQL (for JPA2.0) that would return DemoUserAccounts joined on parent table - UserAccounts? Doing this would assume I can filter on tags/user_roles as well. In general some records will not have DemoUserAccount specific fields filled in.

Comment: Please try to reduce the question to the **absolute minimum**. This will attract additional attention, since it will get easier to reproduce. For example try to use less fields and only those annotations that are relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `SELECT` from DemoUserAccount, you already have the UserAccount fields available to do a query using them.

So, if you want to filter by `email` and `failedLogins`:

```
SELECT d FROM DemoUserAccount d WHERE d.email = 'you@you.com' AND d.failedLogins > 3
```